Using the Maclaurin series of sin(x) to find Si(x)
The Maclaurin series for $\sin\left(x\right)$ is given by: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}$$ So the series for $\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}$ would be $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{2n}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}$$ Therefore, integrating over this sum with respect to $x$ would give one: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}x^{2n+1}}{\left(2n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)!}$$ Is this a correct derivation for $\int\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}dx$?

yes; you can also see the series by checking WolframAlpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+Si%28x%29
